# Cannot import tf-sentencepiece

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tf-sentencepiece with pip, and when I run the line:

```
import tf_sentencepiece as tfs
```

I get the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tf_sentencepiece/_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow20OpKernelConstruction21CtxFailureWithWarningEPKciRKNS_6StatusE
```

Any idea why I can't import the library? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by changing tensorflow version to 1.10.0.